# mariadb: force "SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN" as default parameter

Tags: mariadb, percona

I currently migrate data from Percona 5.5.14 to MariaDB 10.1.22

On a specific query which is using some JOINs, query plan is different between the 2 versions and response time > 400ms

The only solution I've find to solve this is to use STRAIGHT_JOIN option:

Percona 5.5.14  => 150ms

MariaDB 10.1.22 => 550ms ==> 150ms WITH STRAIGHT_JOIN option

My question is: Is there a parameter to force STRAIGHT_JOIN option on each SELECT queries which using JOINs?

I understand it's not a good solution, but I want to know if it exist because I haven't found it

---

Query is call in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
            C.NAME                      AS out_Name,
            RC.ID                       AS out_PlanId,
            ISO.A3                      AS out_A3,
            ISO.NAME                    AS out_CountryName,
            ISO.NUMBER                  AS out_countryNumber,
            C.ID                        AS out_CId,
            RC.NAME                     AS out_CName,
            RSG.NAME                    AS out_ServiceGroupName,
            SPE.id                      AS out_EntryId,
            SPE.GOUPID                  AS out_GroupId,
            ZPE.ZONEID                  AS out_zoneId,
            Z.NAME                      AS out_zoneName,            
            ZPE.ID                      AS out_zoneEntryId,
            ZPE.PREFIX                  AS out_zonePrefix,
            RC.PLANID                   AS out_zonePlanId,
            SPE.ZONEID                  AS out_zoneGroupId,
            ZSG.NAME                    AS out_zoneGroupName,
            SCPA.ID                     AS out_scpAId,
            SCPA.NAME                   AS out_scpAName,
            ZG.ID                       AS out_zoningpId,
            ZG.NAME                     AS out_zoningName,
            IFNULL(SF1.NAME,"")         AS out_Flag_serviceType_name,
            IFNULL(SF2.NAME,"")         AS out_Flag_service_name,
            IFNULL(SF3.NAME,"")         AS out_Flag_zone_name,
            IFNULL(SF4.NAME,"")         AS out_Flag_Plan_name,
            RC.RULEID                   AS out_ruleId,
            RP.NAME                     AS out_ruleName
    FROM 
            table1                      AS M ,
            table2                      AS C,
            table3                      AS RC,
            table3                      AS RP,
            table4                      AS SPE  LEFT JOIN table12 AS SF2 ON SF2.id=SPE.FLAGID,
            table5                      AS ST   LEFT JOIN table11 AS SF1 ON SF1.id=ST.FLAGID,
            table6                      AS RSG,
            table7                      AS ZSG,
            table8                      AS ZPE  LEFT JOIN table14 as SF4 on SF4.id=ZPE.FLAGID,
            table9                      AS ISO,
            table10                     AS NP,
            table11                     AS Z    LEFT JOIN table13 as SF3 on SF3.id=Z.FLAGID ,
            table12                     AS SCPA,
            table13                     AS ZG
    WHERE 
            M.name                          ='TSL'
            AND C.mvno_id                   =M.id
            AND C.id                        ='1010'
            AND RC.id                       =C.ID 
            AND RP.id                       =RC.RULEID
            AND SPE.SERVICEID               =RC.SERVICEID
            AND RSG.ID                      =SPE.GOUP_ID
            AND ST.NAME                     ='GOR'
            AND SPE.SERVICETYPE_ID          =ST.ID
            AND ZSG.ID                      =SPE.ZONEID
            AND ZPE.ZONE_PLAN_ID            =RC.PLANID
            AND NP.NAME                     ='OSI'
            AND ZPE.NUMBERINGPLAN_ID        =NP.ID
            AND ZPE.ISOCOUNTRY_ID           =ISO.ID
            AND ZPE.ZONEID                  =ZSG.ID
            AND Z.ID                        =ZPE.ZONEID
            AND SCPA.ID                     =Z.ACTIONID
            AND ZG.ID                       =Z.GROUPID
            AND ZSG.ID                      =ZPE.ZONEID
            AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
                   BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(IFNULL(ZPE.VALIDFROM,0))
                       AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(IFNULL(ZPE.VALIDUNTIL,"2038-01-01") )              
            AND (
                    (
                        '0'=0 
                        AND ZPE.PREFIX      ='AUT'
                    )
                OR
                    (   '0'=1 
                        AND
                        (
                               substring('AUT',1,1)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,2)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,3)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,4)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,5)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,6)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,7)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,8)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,9)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,10)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,11)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,12)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,13)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,14)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR substring('AUT',1,15)=ZPE.prefix
                            OR  concat('AUT','#') =ZPE.prefix
                        )
                    )
            )
    ORDER BY LENGTH(prefix) DESC 
    LIMIT 1;
```

[EXPLAIN MariaDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMeUb.png)

[EXPLAIN IN PRODUCTION (Percona)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myutQ.png)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to auto-SJ.  Would you care to show us one of the queries, plus `EXPLAIN` (preferably on both servers), and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be some other technique to regain the speed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
For information, it's a stored procedure call in loop (x100)

Answer (score 0):

Put parentheses around the `LEFT JOINs` to make sure they are parsed correctly and the same by both versions:

```
( table4 AS SPE  LEFT JOIN table12 AS SF2 ON SF2.id=SPE.FLAGID ),
( table5 AS ST   LEFT JOIN table11 AS SF1 ON SF1.id=ST.FLAGID  ),
```

At the same time, change the `JOINs` away from "commajoin" to `JOIN .. ON`.  That will make it easier to read.  And, *especially*, make it obvious what is in the `WHERE`.

Since you are obviously generating the SQL, work just a little harder to avoid constructs like `'0'=1`.

Isn't `substring('AUT',1,1)=ZPE.prefix OR substring('AUT',1,2)=ZPE.prefix OR ...` more simply written as just `ZPE.prefix = left('AUT', CHAR_LENGTH(ZPE.prefix`))`?  Once you have change to that, you can probably further simplify that expression, probably getting rid of the other side of the`OR`, and perhaps allowing`INDEX(prefix)` to be useful.

Be aware that `LENGTH()` is the *byte* length; `CHAR_LENGTH()` is the *character* length.

All your `IDs` are `BIGINT`?  Do you really need that much range?  Shrinking the datatype will help performance.

I see `Using intersect`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`ZPE` so we can see what is going on.  *Usually* that optimization is *not* as good as having a 'composite' index.

I realize I have not answered the question you asked.  But I would rather do the above cleanups first.